# I was following the tech with tim flappy bird Python Flappy Bird AI Tutorial (with NEAT)

Tags: python

I was in the 4th video when I encountered a problem. I had just done the main function and ran the program to see how it looks and then got an error as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'Pipe' object has no attribute 'set_height'
```

Here is the part of the code where the error seams to have originated:

```
class Pipe:
    GAP=200
    VEL=5
    
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
        self.height=0
        
        self.top=0
        self.bottom=0
        self.PIPE_TOP=pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG,False,True)
        self.PIPE_BOTTOM=PIPE_IMG   

        self.passed=False
        self.set_height()

        def set_height(self):
            self.height=random.randrange(50,450)
            self.top=self.height- self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
            self.bottom=self.height +self.GAP

        def move(self):
            self.x-=self.VEL
        def draw(self,win):
            win.blit(self.PIPE_TOP,(self.x,self.top))
            win.blit(self.PIPE_BOTTOM,(self.x,self.bottom))
            
        def collide(self,bird):
            bird_mask=bird.get_mask()
            top_mask=pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_TOP)
            bottom_mask=pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_BOTTOM)

            top_offset=(self.x-bird.x,self.top-round(bird.y))
            bottom_offset=(self.x-bird.x,self.bottom-round(bird.y))

            b_point=bird_mask.overlap(bottom_mask,bottom_offset)
            t_point=bird_mask.overlap(top_mask,top_offset)

            if t_point or b_point:
                return True

            return False
```

Please I really want to know what I am doing wrong so that I can learn from It as this is my first time trying to make a game and an AI to run it.
Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Please when asking a question about an error, post the full error. From `Traceback most recent` to the end. Also read about providing a [mre]. Note that Python is an indentation-sensitive language. Unless this is a typo from copy-paste, you need to unindent all your methods to be in the **same** level as `__init__` - not **under** it...

Comment: Yeah I am so sorry but the indentation error in the above program is an error made while copying it and is not the actual error and I am still stuck.

Comment: So please [edit] your question to reflect the exact code you're running. Right now the error seems to match the above, and in that case it's an indentation issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your indentation is the problem here.
Try moving the methods inside `__init__` to the outside, inside the class definition.

```
class Pipe:
    def __init__(self):
        # x, y, 
    def set_height(self):
        # enter code here
    def move(self):
        # stuff
    .
    .
    .
```